# Getting lipo Errors while creating the static libraries in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am working with the creation of static library file.In that i added aggregate and i did the following steps

1.Clicked on the Project Navigator
2.Next clicked on the UniversalLib(Name of the Aggreagte which i have given)
3.Build settings
4.Add build Phase
5.Add Run Script and I expanded the Run Script Module and i wrote the following code

```
# define output folder environment variable
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal
 
# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target ImageFilters ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
xcodebuild -target ImageFilters -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
 
# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
 
# Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"
 
# Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/include" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

6.Then I selected the aggregate target in the Scheme Selection drop down.

7.I am getting the following errors…

```
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StaticLibrary-frasjhywfplfpoetbcefljbwhqcd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libStaticLibrary.a (No such file or directory)

cp: /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StaticLibrary-frasjhywfplfpoetbcefljbwhqcd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include: No such file or directory
```

can anyone please help me to solve this.I searched in so many sites but i didn't find the solution for this.

I am doing this example by following this tutorial....
http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: Since lipo can't find the file where you expect it to be, can you see where "libStaticLibrary.a" is being created?  (Or whether it's created?)  Does the path "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StaticLibrary-frasjhywfplfpoetbcefljbwhqcd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/" exist?

Comment: Actually that "libStaticLibrary.a" is in red color in my app.While i created itself it was in red color.

Comment: You say you created it.  Did it really get created?  If so, where?

Comment: @iworld have you find any solution, am i am looking for same solution?